# Why doesn't this loop run?

Tags: python, django, model, control-flow

As you can see, this code lets the user create models called Images.  The problem is, no images are actually created when I want them to be.  The print test with the obnoxious caps (print images) returns an empty list after I've inputted information multiple times.

Perhaps related to this issue, I simply cannot add print tests to any of the if/else loops in the code.  It returns an indentation error, even when I check all of the indents for four spaces.

I'm really confused.  I suspect I'm misunderstanding the control flow?

#### views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from images_app.models import Image

def index(request):
    images = Image.objects.all()
    image_names = [a.name for a in images]
    print images        ###  THIS RETURNS AN EMPTY LIST!!

    if request.method == 'POST':

        image_string = request.POST.get('get_image')
        index = image_string.find('(')

        # divide input into parent and child
        if index == -1:
            parent = image_string
            child = None
        else:
            parent = image_string[0:index]
            child = image_string[index+1:len(image_string)-1]
         #  print "Child is.. ", child.name   ###  THIS RETURNS AN INDENTATION ERROR

        # create models based on input
        if parent not in image_names and child not in image_names:

            parent_model = Image(name=parent)
            child_model = Image(name=child, parent=parent_model)

        elif parent in image_names and child not in image_names:

            parent_model = images.get(name=parent)
            child_model = Image(name=child, parent=parent_model)

        elif parent not in image_names and child in image_names:

            child_model = images.get(name=child)
            parent_model = Image(name=parent)
            child_model.parent = parent_model
            print "descendants are: ", parent_model.get_descendants()

        else:
            print "else"

    return render(request, 'images_app/index.html', {'images':images})

def get_images(request):
    term = request.GET.get('terms') #jquery-ui.autocomplete parameter
    images = Image.objects.filter(name__istartswith=terms) 
    res = []
    for i in images:
         #make dict with the metadatas that jquery-ui.autocomple needs 
         dict = {'id':i.id, 'label':i.__unicode__(), 'value':i.__unicode__()}
         res.append(dict)
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(res))
```

#### index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <title> images </title>
        <script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        $("#terms").autocomplete({
            source: "{% url 'images_app:get_images' %}",
            minLength: 1,
            });
        });
        </script>            
    </head>
    <nav>
    <a href="/associate">associate</a>
    </nav>
    <body>

        {% for images in images %}
            {{ image.name }} 
        {% endfor %}

        <section>
            <h1>create an image</h1>

            <form action="{% url 'images_app:index' %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}

                <div class="ui-widget">
                    <label for="get_image">create image: </label>
                    <input id="get_image" name="get_image">
                </div>
                <div id="buttons">
                    <input type="submit" value="create" class="submit" name="create" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>

    </body>
```

Comment: Is there any entry in your database?

Comment: @MaximeLorant   No, it turns out that I didn't even include save statements!  Programming is good for exposing one's absent mindedness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't ever save any of your images.

Doing `Image(blah)` simply instantiates an object in memory. You need to call `.save()` on the instance, or alternatively do `Image.objects.create(blah)` to instantiate and save at the same time.

Comment: This doesn't resolve the issue of not being able to insert statements after instantiating the models.  When I try to insert 'parent_model.save() statements on the same indentation level, it gives me an indentation error no matter what.  The indentation of the save() is exactly the same as that of the parent_model etc, so I'm stumped.  It's not related, but it prevents me from resolving the issue.

Comment: You're probably mixing tabs and spaces. Make sure your text editor is configured to insert only spaces when you press the Tab key.

Comment: I'm not using the tab key at all.  Just four spaces.  Supposedly there's an indentation error in this line:       

if parent not in image_names and child not in image_names:

            parent_model = Image(name=parent)
      parent_model.save()
            child_model = Image(name=child, parent=parent_model)
      child_model.save()

Comment: Double check that your editor does not replace "spaces" with tabs... (many do so, "out of the box")

Comment: edit:  brought it into IDLE and tabified it, now it's working.  thanks for your help.